# Create-react-app: Experimental syntax 'classProperties' isn't currently enabled

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, create-react-app

I am using create-react-app and don't want to eject. Is there any-other way to fix this?

```
   class SlidingUpPanel extends React.Component {
   static propTypes = {
               ^
   visible: PropTypes.bool,
   height: PropTypes.number,   draggableRange: PropTypes.shape({
```

`Add @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties (https://git.io/vb4SL) to the 'plugins' section of your Babel config to enable transformation.`

Installed `@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties` already!
But how to fix this without ejecting?

Comment: which version of react-scripts do you have?

Comment: @azium `"react-scripts": "2.1.0"`

Comment: hmm strange, this should already be supported then. is the code in your `src` folder? are you getting this error in the terminal when running your code?

Comment: so i am trying to use `https://github.com/octopitus/rn-sliding-up-panel` this library and yes my code is in src! and i am getting this error in terminal and also on the screen!
some say you have to eject and then edit the config fine and make babelrc: true so then you can just add plugins and do more but i dont want to eject!

Comment: you shouldn't need to eject. i'm a little confused though. create-react-app is for the web. isn't that a react-native component?

Comment: Oh shit! i feel dumb!
i totally got it wrong! and yes i just read it. its a react native plugin *bang my head on wall*

Comment: can you recommend me something like this for web? doing pwa

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186168/discussion-between-bilal-and-azium).