# create-react-app with Typescript : Support for the experimental syntax 'classProperties' isn't currently enabled

Tags: reactjs, typescript, babeljs, create-react-app

I created a react app with `npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript` and added the react component [rn-sliding-up-panel](https://github.com/octopitus/rn-sliding-up-panel). I know that rn stands for react native but the solution is pure js and works fine on the web.

Now I get `Support for the experimental syntax 'classProperties' isn't currently enabled (35:20): Add @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties (https://git.io/vb4SL) to the 'plugins' section of your Babel config to enable transformation.`

Which is an awesome informative error message. Unfortunately I don't have an babel configuration since i want to do my whole transpiling with typescript.

I already tried to add the configuration to my package.json, but whitout any luck

```
{
  "name": "slider-test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      "@babel/preset-react"
    ],
    "plugins": [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.24",
    "@types/node": "^12.12.21",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.16",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.4",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.3.0",
    "rn-sliding-up-panel": "^2.4.0",
    "typescript": "^3.7.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.7.4"
  }
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you consider *ejecting* the app?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54035203/create-react-app-experimental-syntax-classproperties-isnt-currently-enabled

Comment: I hoped i get around ejecting the app, but I guess I will try this as next step.

Comment: It' seems like you have two ways to go: 1. Ejecting; 2. Forking react scripts and implementing it there, but you have to maintain your fork.